The import com.mongodb cannot be resolved - Gradle (Kotlin) -
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;
import org.bson.Document;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;


where as the "com.mongodb" is underlined in red
my build.gradle:
dependencies {
//  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.modulith:spring-modulith-starter-core'
//  implementation 'org.springframework.modulith:spring-modulith-starter-mongodb'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.modulith:spring-modulith-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:5.1.0'
    implementation 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:5.1.0'
    implementation 'org.mongodb:bson:5.1.0'
  //  implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
    
     compileOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
        }
    
}


Have some stuff commented out to try to resolve it. If anyone has seen this before and could help, that would be awesome, thanks
I tried removing dependencies, running clean builds after every change of a dependency and still haven't got anything. However, I get a
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.lambda$open$0(SocketStream.java:86) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:86) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:226) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitor.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:216) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitor.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:173) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.1.0.jar:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:547) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:602) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:76) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:105) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:80) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.1.0.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted

when doing a bootRun so I know mongo is being hit. It just can't import it to any classes.
ALL FILES ARE IN SAME DIRECTORY, under src/main/java/

The exception is about not able to connect to the database server.

Looks like an IDE issue as you can run the program and access those classes. Clear caches/repair project etc
